# Orbeon: Make all non-read-only fields required (globally)

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have a big form with many input controls (400+). For many of them, I added rules so they are read-only unless a certain other field is set to "no".

Example:

```
Do you agree with XXX? yes [ ]  no [ ]
Reason: __________________  <--(textfield that is read-only unless "no" is selected)
```

Now I would like that all non-read-only fields are required. How can I do this without adding a (conditional) required-rule to every single input control? Because doing so would take forever and also it seems like bad practice to me to apply a rule that we can formulate globally to every single element...

I thought about using a script and doing something like this:

```
<xf:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed" type="javascript">
    ORBEON.jQuery('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
        if (ORBEON.jQuery(this).is(':disabled')) {
            // what now??? is there something like "ORBEON.jQuery(this).makeRequired();" ?
        } 
    });
</xf:action>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this in JavaScript, but could do it in XForms. Assuming you're creating the form with Form Builder, you can do this by editing the source of form, and adding the following inside the `<xf:model>`. With this you are, quite plainly I think, saying that all nodes are required if they are not read-only.

```
<xf:bind ref="instance('fr-form-instance')//*" required="not(xxf:readonly())"/>
```

You can also reset the values of all read-only fields by "overriding" the "save" process as follows. Note that everything here is standard, and only the `xf:setvalue(ref = "//*[xxf:readonly()]")` is added.

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-final.*.*">
    require-uploads
    then validate-all
    then xf:setvalue(ref = "//*[xxf:readonly()]")
    then save
    then new-to-edit
    then success-message("save-success")
    recover error-message("database-error")
</property>
```

Comment: Hmm, it actually makes ALL fields required, even readonly-fields... But thanks anyway, I didn't think that things like that could be done using XForms. For now, I just did some regex search-replace on the whole xml source to add the required="true" for all fields.

But why should i not do this in JavaScript? What if I need more sophisticated checks/actions, like clearing all readonly-fields when the user submits the form (which is actually something I would like to do).

Comment: Doing things in JavaScript might work, but is more fragile, at 2 levels: first, there is a chance that the JavaScript behaves differently on different browsers (existing and future), and second, a malicious users can get around your JavaScript, while they can't possibly get around a rule you define in XForms, because it is also enforced for you on the server.

Comment: Regarding the fields you want to clear on submit, are you talking about read-only fields, or of hidden fields? The latter is more usual, and we have a request for enhancement [#2760](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2760) for this. Would this satisfy your requirement, or are you looking for something different?

Comment: I am talking about read-only fields, not hidden fields. Idea is: there are many fields that switch their read-only state depending on a previous yes-no answer and I only want to save non-read-only fields. But I also don't want all read-only fields to be cleared as soon as they become read-only (because user might change state by accident). Instead I'd like to clear them when the form is saved. 
I just found that there is an attribute `xf:relevant`, I think I could solve this issue by adding a rule that makes read-only fields not `xf:relevant` so they're not stored.. Might come back to that :)

Comment: Got it, then you could override the "save" process to reset the value of read-only fields. I've updated my answer above to include the property you can use for this. You'll let me know if this works for you. And I added a note about this also making sense for read-only fields to issue [#2760](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2760).

Comment: @Tagas Just wondering: did you already get a chance to try the `xf:setvalue()` in the process, and if so, did it work for you?

Comment: thanks for asking! Couldn't test it yet unfortunately, because I don't have access to properties-local.xml. Is it possible to put this property directly in the form-source? (I only have access to the Orbeon form builder). If so, where? Tried head and model, neither worked...

Comment: @Tagas Currently, it isn't: processes are defined in properties. We're working on a UI to allow form authors to define processes in Form Builder, but that work isn't done yet :). So, for now, you'll need to ask someone to change the `properties-local.xml`. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Ok, good enough, at least there is a way. Happy to receive good support here, thanks :)

Comment: @Tagas Got it, and always glad to help!